# Remove extra space from framed environment

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, framed, enumitem

I would like to remove or better said have the framed environment (box) aligned with the content in the description. Notice below how the box is out of alignment and aligns with the margin. See a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{description}
    \item[Test] \lipsum[1]
    \begin{framed}
        \textbf{Understanding the Problem}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[0:] Complete misunderstanding of the problem
        \item[5:] Part of the problem misunderstood or misinterpreted
        \item[10:] Complete understanding of the problem
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{framed}
    \end{description}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility, using the `framed` environment from the `framed` package as requested:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{framed}{%
 \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin
 \fboxsep=\FrameSep\fbox{##1}
     \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
 \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
   \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
   \@setminipage}}%
 {\par\unskip\endMakeFramed}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
    \begin{description}
    \item[Test] \lipsum*[1]
    \begin{framed}
        \textbf{Understanding the Problem}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[0:] Complete misunderstanding of the problem
        \item[5:] Part of the problem misunderstood or misinterpreted
        \item[10:] Complete understanding of the problem
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{framed}
    \end{description}
\lipsum[4]
    \begin{framed}
        \textbf{Understanding the Problem}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[0:] Complete misunderstanding of the problem
        \item[5:] Part of the problem misunderstood or misinterpreted
        \item[10:] Complete understanding of the problem
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can the padding(FrameSep) be retained globally? I ask because I am using the framed environment somewhere else and the code above is also affecting it.

Comment: @azetina please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

Search and replace `framed` by `mdframed` in your WME:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{description}
    \item[Test] \lipsum[1]
    \begin{mdframed}
        \textbf{Understanding the Problem}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[0:] Complete misunderstanding of the problem
        \item[5:] Part of the problem misunderstood or misinterpreted
        \item[10:] Complete understanding of the problem
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{mdframed}
    \end{description}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This didn't helped :(

Comment: @alper  This is a very old post, but both my TeX Live 2018 as well as [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) produce exactly the same output that is showed with the MWE posted. Tha is, with the frame aligned as demanded in the question. So, the solution is correct for an `article` class with the  `enumitem` package, in a description environment. Of course, I cannot guarantee that it will work in any other scenario, but if this not help, chances are that you are doing something wrong,  aside of using some weird class, some incompatible package, or an outdated installation.